# Dependencies conflict issue in android studio's build.gradle file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am having a problem in placing the right dependencies in build.gradle file.
I have posted the screenshot of the issue. PLEASE HELP!!!!!!!!!!!
[Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe77z.png)

Comment: Doesn't the error tell you exactly what to do?

Comment: not exactly. I have tried a lot to experiment a lot with different versions and still not able to resolve

Comment: Please have a look at the screenshot and tell me whether i am using the correct versions of the dependencies.

Comment: use 10.0.1 version. issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First, add rules to your root-level build.gradle file, to include the google-services plugin:

```
   buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

Then, in your module Gradle file (usually the app/build.gradle), add the apply plugin line at the bottom of the file to enable the Gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: i tried that but still throwing the error "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1."

Comment: Please have a look at the screenshot and tell me whether i am using the correct versions of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is solved now following are the changes i made it:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.6'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

For 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
it was before 10.0.1 and I changed to 10.2.6 and synced it

AND

For
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.6' 
it was before 10.0.1 and I changed to 10.2.6 and synced it and it worked..

Thank you everyone :)

Comment: This is what I exactly have but still facing Error:(47, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.6 more help please.